# How to read PDFs with Hindi text in R?

Tags: r, parsing, pdf, nlp, hindi

I have multiple typed PDFs with Hindi text. I need to create a data frame using all the PDFs for further analysis. I am using R for this.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] pdftools_3.0.1  textreadr_1.0.2 tm_0.7-8        NLP_0.2-1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7        pillar_1.6.1      compiler_4.0.3    tools_4.0.3       lfe_2.8-6         lifecycle_1.0.0  
 [7] tibble_3.1.2      lattice_0.20-41   pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.11      Matrix_1.2-18     DBI_1.1.1        
[13] parallel_4.0.3    xfun_0.23         dplyr_1.0.6       xml2_1.3.2        generics_0.1.0    vctrs_0.3.8      
[19] askpass_1.1       grid_4.0.3        tidyselect_1.1.0  data.table_1.13.2 glue_1.4.2        qpdf_1.1         
[25] R6_2.5.0          fansi_0.4.1       sp_1.4-4          Formula_1.2-4     purrr_0.3.4       magrittr_2.0.1   
[31] ellipsis_0.3.2    assertthat_0.2.1  xtable_1.8-4      sandwich_3.0-1    utf8_1.1.4        tinytex_0.32     
[37] slam_0.1-48       crayon_1.4.1      zoo_1.8-9
```

I have tried using the following :

```
library(tm)
library(pdftools)

file <- 'pdf_file.pdf'

dat = readPDF(control=list(text="-layout"))(elem=list(uri=file), 
                                            language="UTF-8", id="id1") 

library(textreadr)

pdf_dat <- read_pdf(system.file("pdf_file.pdf", package = "textreadr"))

pdf_text(file)
```

However, the result I get looks like :

```
   27 ªF³F½FSXeX XY2012\n\n                                                                                                                                                                                       ¸FûQe ³FZ d½FIYFÀF °Fû dIY¹FF W` : IYFa¦FiZÀF\n                                                                                                                                                                                         w ¦F„þSF°F IYFa¦FiZÀF IZY d½FÄFF´F³F ¸FZÔ dQJe          ¦F„þSF°Fe IYû d½FIYFÀF ´F„÷Y¿F ¶F°FF°FZ W„E SFª¹F IZY        IYFa¦FiÀZ F ³FZ ¹FWX ÀFaQVZ F QZ³FZ IYe IYFZdVFVF þøYSX            QþÊ³F C°ÀF½FûÔ IYF ¶FûÓF OXF»F³FZ IYF AFSû´F\n                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ³F¦FSX ÀFaÀIYSX¯F\n
```

An example PDF for this purpose can be downloaded from [here](https://vk.com/doc562341376_609941034?hash=fb68b749b7aebfdd87&dl=0b94ca877de3492686).

Thank You!

Comment: I have no issue with reading the file using `pdftools::pdf_text` or using `readtext::readtext`. Everything comes in fine in UTF-8. But what you are trying to read in, will never be in the correct order. pdftools reads from left to right and doesn't take all the different columns in account. So all the words on 1 line will be from multiple articles instead of per article.

Comment: Can you please share your code? I am not able to read it correctly with UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

As requested the code(s) I use for reading in the pdf while keeping the `Encoding`.

with tm:

```
library(tm)
library(pdftools)

text <- pdf_text("NBT-16-Aug-2021.pdf")
corp <- VCorpus(VectorSource(text))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
inspect(dtm[1:3, 1:3])
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 3, terms: 3)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 2/7
Sparsity           : 78%
Maximal term length: 5
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
    Terms
Docs                       \033पेज                             'अपनी                      'अपर
   1                            5                                 1                         0
   2                            0                                 0                         0
   3                            0                                 0                         0
```

or

```
dat <- VCorpus(URISource("NBT-16-Aug-2021.pdf", mode = ""),
               readerControl = list(reader = readPDF(engine = "pdftools")))

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(dat)
inspect(dtm)
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 1, terms: 3)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 3/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 5
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
                     Terms
Docs                                        \033पेज                             'अपनी                      'अपर
  NBT-16-Aug-2021.pdf                            5                                 1                         1
```

With quanteda:

```
library(readtext)
library(quanteda)
text <- readtext("NBT-16-Aug-2021.pdf")
corp <- corpus(text)
my_dfm <- dfm(tokens(corp))
head(featfreq(my_dfm), 20)

                             yo                                        u 
                               2                                        3 
                               n                                        g 
                              14                                        3 
                               i                                        d 
                               2                                        1 
                               a                                        > 
                               3                                        5 
                              pa                                        p 
                               1                                        1 
                               e                                        r 
                               2                                        2 
                               ि                                    पर्यंका 
                               3                                       10 
                               ने                                     भारत 
                             718                                       74 
                              की                                      मदद 
                             915                                       19 
                               क                                        ि 
                            1870                                     2567
```

My preference is working with quanteda as it keeps the UTF-8 better across all operations. tm sometimes loses them when you try cleaning. Also quanteda can works in parallel out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for the code! I am still not getting the output like you got. Can we connect on Zoom?